# How to set an environment variable programmatically in Jenkins/Hudson?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, environment-variables, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

I have two scripts in the pre-build step in a Jenkins job, the first one a perl script, the second a system groovy script using the groovy plugin. I need information from the first perl script in my second groovy script. I think the best way would be to set some environment variable, and was wondering how that can be realized.

Or any other better way.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This question involves project-specific environment variables, but for global environment variables, please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39004253/2074605).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way to propagate environment variables among build steps is via [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

Here are some previous answers that show how to do it:

- [How to set environment variables in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626193/1178189)
- [Jenkins : Report results of intermediate [windows batch] build steps in email body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626180/1178189)

In your case, however, it may be simpler just to write to a file in one build step and read that file in another. To make sure you do not accidentally read from a previous version of the file you can incorporate `BUILD_ID` in the file name.

Comment: Workspace is always separate for each build so there is no need to add a `build_id`. If you will add build_id you will end up with a lot of files eventually. It's better to simply start by removing old file if it exists (or simply overwrite it).

Comment: It really depends on your use case. If you want to preserve the content of the file for a later usage you need to add the build-id in the file name. If you will only use the latest build info, then you can always replace it.

Answer (score 3):

Using [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) from job configuration you should use `Inject environment variables to the build process / Evaluated Groovy script`.

Depending on the setup you may execute `Groovy` or `shell` command and save it in map containing environment variables:

## Example

By either getting command result with `execute` method:

```java
return [DATE: 'date'.execute().text]
```

or with `Groovy` equivalent if one exists:

```java
return [DATE: new Date()]
```