# How to share config set by developers for multiple jobs

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, microservices

Our team develops micro-monolith application. Which means that our applications is spitted to multiple modules like in microservice pattern but run on tomcats not containers.
We used to have linear workflow:

Environments: dev -> qa -> production

Where after each commit to dev Jenkins automatically build, run tests and deployed application to dev environment.
But lately we see that sometimes there is need to develop multiple excluding features simultaneously and we would want to have multiple dev environments.

**Is there a way to allow developers to easly set and see shared properties in Jenkins?** i.e. pars feature_branch_name=environment_name

```
Feature_branch_123=alfa
Feature_branch_124=bravo
```

So always on beginning of working on feature, person sets this property and later when (s)he pushes changes to repository Jenkins can automatically build and deploy given commit for previously set environment. Sharing is required because we have one build pipeline for each service and we want to be able to share this configuration across whole application.

In similar cases of sharing config between steps people [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10789484/1678568) use of [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), but I don't think this would be good solution here there would be no easy way to set parameters, the best way I could think of is by use of parameterized job, and also then people doesn't have possibility to see what parameters are currently set.