# Jenkins - how to use variable in file name

Tags: bash, jenkins

In execute shell in build settings I have PROJECT_VERSION variable. I would like to use it in FTP Publishers -> Transfer -> Source files in that way:

```
build/project_${PROJECT_VERSION}.zip
```

but it seems to not be working. How to export this information? I tried also "export" command but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really have to specify the project version? I usually use a wildcard to specify source files when transferring using SSH at least. E.g.

```
build/project_*.zip
```

Otherwise you could take a look at this: [How to set an environment variable programmatically in Jenkins/Hudson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789341/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-programmatically-in-jenkins-hudson)

Comment: Ok... I can use * in Source files (if I have only one) but I need also add this PROJECT_VERSION to "Remote directory". I want use it in that way: SOMETHING/iOS/${PROJECT_VERSION} - there I can't use *.

Comment: You could use the solution given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10626193/5533897

Comment: @piotr-wasilewicz Another possibility would be to place the built zip files at`build/${PROJECT_VERSION}/project_${PROJECT_VERSION}.zip` and then set "Source files" to `build/**/*.zip`, "Remove prefix" to `build` and "Remote directory" to `SOMETHING/iOS. But this may be a bit ugly ;)

Comment: Your previous solution (stackoverflow.com/a/10626193/5533897) works great. Thank you!