# Jenkins: Can parameters be passed into Jenkins (Config files or Command Line arguments)?

Tags: selenium, jenkins

My team is working on setting up Jenkins to run our automation. This is working, now.

However, we would like to explore the possibility of passing an argument in through the command line, or adding a config file on the fly, that goes into the dll of our test solution and alters certain, limited values.

For example:
There are three tests, and our global login variable is pointing to our integration environment. However, for just one of the tests, we want to override the environment variable and point to our test environment instead.

Can this be done with Jenkins? I can't find anything detailing this in the Jenkins documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set an environment variable programmatically in Jenkins/Hudson?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789341/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-programmatically-in-jenkins-hudson)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10789341/3124333 ?

Comment: Check out [Parameterized Builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, and sorry for missing the current answers to this question. To help others than stumble on this question/answer, look at the following:

```
[Yes, you can do this (1)][1]
[Yes (2)][2]
[Yes (2)][3]
[Here's the plugin to do this][4]
```

1: [How to set environment variables in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins/10626193#10626193)

2: [Jenkins : Report results of intermediate [windows batch] build steps in email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623969/jenkins-report-results-of-intermediate-windows-batch-build-steps-in-email-bo/10626180#10626180)

3: [How to set an environment variable programmatically in Jenkins/Hudson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789341/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-programmatically-in-jenkins-hudson)

4: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin