# Jenkins Custom Email Properties From Pre Send Script

Tags: bash, email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I have a script in the pre send script which is a bash script and looks like the below

```
if [ $TRIMMED_MONTH -eq 01 ]
then
    $MONTH=“January”
```

and continues for all the months.

I then want to access the property $MONTH in the email body text.

How can I go about accessing that property?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623969/jenkins-report-results-of-intermediate-windows-batch-build-steps-in-email-bo/10626180#10626180 ?

Comment: @ManuelBarbe I have the envinject plugin installed on my machine, but when I tick the box to installent Environment Variables, i then have 5 more boxes to fill in which I dont understand, and then dont know how to access the variables. Massive newbie here